# Check Engine on, raster says it's EGR on Ford Ranger 95 STX

Tags: ford, ranger, egr

The dreaded "Check Engine" light is on on my Ford Ranger 95 STX SuperCab, 6V 4.0. The raster says it's "EGR" but nothing else. I've heard a lot about gasoline quality or the cathalizer, but the cathalizer is good and I can't change the gasoline. I'm in Brazil, where the gasoline has around 25% of ethanol on it. What can I fix or change to turn it off? Thanks.

Comment: EGR = Exhaust Gas Return. What makes you think you have a gasoline problem, as opposed to an EGR valve problem? My 1991 Ford 4.0 V6 needed EGR valve replacement at around 90k miles...

Comment: This is something that is commonly believed in Brazil.

Comment: Solved by switching the EGR valve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this warning by replacing the EGR and the DPF valves, and now the engine is more responsive and no more Check Engine light on.